Camera calibration using checker board
I have made a setup in blender like this
blender setup. The size of the checkerboard is 2m in height and width of 2m. How should i calculate the 3D positions of each corner? Where should i keep the orgin?
I want to calculate intrinsic matrix (fx and fy). I have the focal length of camera 50mm.
This is what i tried:
     import cv2
     import numpy as np
     import os
     import glob

     # Define the dimensions of the checkerboard
     CHECKERBOARD = (7, 7)
     num_rows = 7
     num_cols = 7
     width = 2  # meters
     height = 2  # meters
     origin_offset_x = 0.25
     origin_offset_y = 0.25

     # Calculate the spacing between corners
     x_spacing = 0.25
     y_spacing = 0.25

     # Initialize an empty array to store corner positions
     arr_3d = np.zeros((num_rows * num_cols, 3), dtype=np.float64)

     # Fill the array with corner positions
     for i in range(num_rows):
          for j in range(num_cols):
             index = i * num_cols + j
             x = origin_offset_x + i * x_spacing
             y = origin_offset_y + j * y_spacing
             arr_3d[index] = [x, y, 0]

    # Reshape the array to include an extra dimension
    corner_positions_3D = arr_3d.reshape(1, 49, 3)

    # Extracting path of individual image stored in a given directory
    images = glob.glob('C:/Users/uig40328/Downloads/blenderout/*.png')

    objpoints = []  # 3D point in real world space
    imgpoints = []  # 2D points in image plane.

    for filename in images:
        image = cv2.imread(filename)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Find the chessboard corners
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, CHECKERBOARD, cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH +
                                             cv2.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK + cv2.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE)

    # If desired number of corners can be detected
    if ret == True:
        # Refine the pixel coordinates of corners
        corners = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11, 11), (-1, -1),
                                    (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30,0.001))

        # Append the refined corners to the list
        objpoints.append(corner_positions_3D[0])
        imgpoints.append(corners)

        # Draw and label the corners
        for i, corner in enumerate(corners):
            x, y = corner.ravel()
            cv2.circle(image, (int(x), int(y)), 3, (0, 255, 0), -1)
            cv2.putText(image, str(i),(int(x),int(y)),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255,        255), 2)

        # Display the image with labeled corners
        cv2.imshow('Labeled Corners', image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)

     cv2.destroyAllWindows()

       # Convert the lists of points to arrays
      objpoints = np.array([objpoints])
      imgpoints = np.array(imgpoints)
      k1 = 345.7533
      k2 = -11.559854
      k3 = 44.552719
      k4 = -51.553291

      D = np.array([k1, k2, k3, k4], dtype=np.float64).reshape(-1, 1)

# Perform camera calibration
     ret, cameraMatrix, rvecs,tvecs ,_ = cv2.fisheye.calibrate(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, D)

print("Camera Matrix:")
print(cameraMatrix)
print(ret)
print(tvecs)

I took left top corner as orgin and calculated the 3D points. Actual thing I want to calculate is rotation and translation, the output I'm getting is wrong, so I feel I'm making a mistake in the way I'm calculating 3D points. Can anybody tell me what mistake I'm doing?
